# Why do images need to be surrounded in div/span elements for effects to work properly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-effects

I don't particularly understand why an image would work in a span, but not by itself.
See complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/DVcKu/1/).

### JS

```
 $(document).ready(
     function ()
     {
        $('#banner').hover( function(event){ $(this).children().hide("slow");}
                          , function(event){ $(this).children().show("slow");}
                          );
     }
  );
```

### HTML

```
<div id="banner">
   <span><img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif" title="Image" alt="Image"/></span>
</div>
```

#### vs

```
<div id="banner">
   <img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif" title="Image" alt="Image"/>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine in the link you provided

Comment: The show does not work properly on the spanless image in FF3.6.11/IE7.

Comment: when you wrap around a div , you will get lot of flexiblity with it, we can not  do all them with just the image.

Comment: @gov: i think we arrived at the same conclusion at the same time.  I'm guessing this has to do with the layout nature of block vs inline.  To me it's weird that it would work part of the way; I would have expected all-or-nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think really the element needs to be wrapped in a DIV.  For my site, a larger image is having problems hiding; it's only hiding vertically instead of vertically and horizontally.

Wrapping in the DIV fixed this.

I haven't taken a greater look at how jQuery is performing the `hide()`, but this kind of makes sense, since a `DIV` is a block element and `SPAN` are not.